# Clear Data Of All the Applications from Your Application (Launcher)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-launcher

I have created an application which is working as a launcher. In that application I have opening various other apps. In that app I want to clear all the data(i.e login details, search history) of other application to be removed on click of a button.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method m:methods){
                if(m.getName().equals("freeStorage")){
                    try{
                        long desiredFreeStorage = Long.MAX_VALUE;
                        m.invoke(pm,desiredFreeStorage,null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Using the above code, I am able to delete the cache but not able to delete the data of other apps.

Please provide me a solution for that.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal behavior. you can't delete data that belongs to other Apps via your app. Files that contain data are private and only accessible by Apps that own them or shared by App.

For example, most of the Apps use `SharedPreference` as private files to save data for later use. So, its senseless if other Apps are allowed to delete that data.